# Combine result as group by matching same key in php

Tags: php

I have a result like this:

[image]

Using foreach loop i can get the output like this:

```html
<ul>
<li>1   group1  group1_title    group1_link 2</li>
<li>2   group1  group1_title    group1_link 1</li>
<li>3   group2  group2_title    group2_link 2</li>
<li>4   group2  group2_title    group2_link 1</li>
<li>5   group3  group3_title    group3_link 2</li>
<li>6   group3  group3_title    group3_link 1</li>
<li>7   group3  group3_title    group3_link 2</li>
</ul>
```

But I need to make the result like this:

```html
<ul data-group="1">
<li>1   group1  group1_title    group1_link 2</li>
<li>2   group1  group1_title    group1_link 1</li>
</ul>
<ul data-group="2">
<li>1   group2  group2_title    group2_link 2</li>
<li>2   group2  group2_title    group2_link 1</li>
</ul>
<ul data-group="3">
<li>1   group3  group3_title    group3_link 2</li>
<li>2   group3  group3_title    group3_link 1</li>
<li>3   group3  group3_title    group3_link 2</li>
</ul>
```

Here is my simple php code

```php
if ($getlinks->num_rows() > 0)
{
    $x = 0;
    foreach ($getlinks->result() as $group)
    {
        $x++;
        echo '<ul group="'.$x.'">';
        echo '<li>'.$group->id.' - '.$group->group.' - '.$group->title.' - '.$group->link.' - '.$group->value.'</li>';
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
```

**Update:** 
using bellow code i can group by value but i need make something like this by key not value

````php
$people = array("Peter", "Peter", "Joe", "Glenn", "Cleveland");

//echo current($people) . "<br>";
//echo end($people);
foreach ($people as $p){
    echo ($p);
    if (current($people) !== next($people)){
    echo " bah<br>";
    }
}```
````

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Stop trying to code your overall goal & explain what you expected instead from the given code & why.

Comment: @philipxy I added more example

Comment: @sumonst21 Why do you want to output it via `<ul>` and `<li>` and not show the table data with an actual `<table>` element?

Comment: @Progman can you show me an example to do it in a table?

Comment: @sumonst21 Check any HTML tutorial on how to make a table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to track when the group changes:

```
if ($getlinks->num_rows() > 0)
{
    $x = 0;
    $prev_group = null;
    foreach ($getlinks->result() as $group)
    {
        // I am assuming $group->id can't be null for an actual group
        if ( $group->id !== $prev_group ) {
           if ( $x > 0 ) {
              // Close previous group
              echo '</ul>';
           }
           echo '<ul group="'.$group->id.'">';
           $x = 0;
           $prev_group = $group->id;
        }
        $x++;
        echo '<li>'$x.' - '.$group->id.' - '.$group->group.' - '.$group->title.' - '.$group->link.' - '.$group->value.'</li>';
    }
    if ( $x > 0 ) {
       // Close last group
       echo '</ul>';
   }
}
```

I'm not clear what your data structures are and if it's `$group->id` or `$group->group` that should be compared, but you see the idea I hope.